# Stick SVG to bottom right of screen using css

Tags: javascript, html, css, svg, web

The CSS class called .svgImage is applied to a `<div>` on the page. Every time I resize the browser window, the svg image resizes correctly but it keeps moving around the page.

For example, making the browser window vertically smaller will move the svg image upwards. And horizontally smaller will move the svg leftwards.

The svg image needs to stay stuck to the bottom right. Imagine the svg file as a four corner square, the bottom right corner should stick to the bottom right corner of the page.

Here is the CSS for the div to stick:

```
.foo {
  background: url(images/GraphicElementDesktop.svg);
  opacity: 1;
  height: 45%;
  width: 33%;
  position: absolute;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  right: 0px;
  bottom: 0px;
  z-index: 5000;
  filter: alpha(opacity=25) progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(opacity=25);
}
```

Any ideas how I can fix this issue?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why is this getting down voted? Can someone tell me before downvoting at least? I can't see anything that is against the SO rules.

Comment: You could add HTML as well

Comment: @TobiObeck There isn't any html except the fact that the class is added to a div inside the body as stated. :)

Comment: that wasn't clear from your question.

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).  See [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to add

```
background-position: right bottom;
```

working fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/411dxm1n/1/

Comment: Sorry, I've edited the CSS now. Have a look now please?

Comment: Omg yes! Thank you so much!